# How do I resolve this error on my namecheap server

Tags: php, codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
> Line Number: 120

This is what I have on the line in the specified file:

```
// Do we have a socket path?
if ($this->hostname[0] === '/')
{
    $hostname = NULL;
    $port = NULL;
    $socket = $this->hostname;
}
else
{
    $hostname = ($persistent === TRUE)
        ? 'p:'.$this->hostname : $this->hostname;
    $port = empty($this->port) ? NULL : $this->port;
    $socket = NULL;
}
```

Comment: it means `$this->hostname` is null

Comment: So what should I do because it has always run through in other applications I have hosted.

Comment: please added detail for your CI framework version. If this old CI, please upgrade into new. If this is new or late (3.* ), you can report this into CI group, because this consider a bug..   There is 3 solution: hide the warning, fix to make sure no warning, or submit the bug and the community fixed it

Comment: Thank you, I have hid the warning.

I will download a new CI and start working with it.